# loop slider is not being called

Tags: jquery

I have this slider.

```
$(function () {
    $(".fadein a").first().show();
    var lnthofimages = $('.fadein a').length;
    var index = 0;
    var count = lnthofimages;

    function bannerRotator() {
        $('.fadein a').delay(5).eq(index).fadeOut(function () {
            if (index == count) {
                index = -1;
            }

            $('.fadein a').eq(index + 1).fadeIn(function () {
                index++;
                bannerRotator();
            });

        });
    }
    bannerRotator();
});
```

Where images are not being rotated. It is not being cycled according to another condition i've given here-

```
$('.fadein a').eq(index + 1).fadeIn(function () {
    index++;
    bannerRotator();
});
```

You can see it here-

http://jsfiddle.net/94bGB/

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? As far as I can see the demo is working for me..

Comment: works fine? it just doesn't start again once its finished? what's actually this issue?

Comment: Minor change: http://jsfiddle.net/94bGB/1/ At line 17 u forgot " in `<a href=#">`

Comment: @ndsmyter, This loop is not being cycled. I want to show these in cycle manner.

Comment: @jbyrne2007, This loop is not being cycled. I want to show these in cycle manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/94bGB/3/

I updated the line here, because your index goes from 0 to 5 but your count is 6, you need to compare the index to the count-1.

```
if (index == count-1) {
    index = -1;
}
```